# Different partial zooms using keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, window-manager, zooming

When coal was young I was using fvwm (or maybe tvwm?) which allowed me to define many different zooms and control them using keyboard, something like

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>: make the window fill the left half of the screen
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>top</kbd>: the same for the top half
- <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>pgdown</kbd>: zoom horizontally

and so on. Pressing the key again restored the original size.

How can I do it with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiz grid plugin is what you want. You can use Cntrl + Alt + NumPad keys for what aligning to top left, right, etc.